# ColdFusion Mail: Automatic generated email?

Tags: coldfusion, coldfusion-8, cfmail

I'm working on building a automatic system where our staff can fill out a form for CPR certifications. I need a way to generate a email automatically and send a reminder to the staff person in charge that Xyz person's certifications expire on X date, ideally something like 2 months before, 1 month before then 2 weeks before.

Anyway to build such an automated email system in cold fusion? Sorry if this is dumb question, I just started in ColdFusion TWO weeks ago.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, the ColdFusion administrator has a built in task scheduler that you can use to run a nightly process that will send the emails you'd like.

http://help.adobe.com/en_US/ColdFusion/9.0/Admin/WSc3ff6d0ea77859461172e0811cbf3638e6-7fe0.html#WSc3ff6d0ea77859461172e0811cbf3638e6-7fd8

Comment: Does that exist in ColdFusion 8?

Comment: yes, you can also schedule task through code using cfschedule tag wich gives you more flexibility.

Answer (score 0):

What you can do is have a nightly scheduled task that checks against a signup date to generate these events.

Even easier might be to use something like MailChimp as it already has it built in.  Integrating to their API is a breeze if needed.